# C++: Using remove_if to filter vector on a condition

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, erase

What is the correct syntax to use erase+remove_if to remove all elements in a vector, that are smaller than a specific value. However, this specific value is not a constant, but a variable.

Refer to the code to get a better understanding of the question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
{
    int currEle = arr[i];

    /*
        How do I use erase + remove_if to remove the elements from arr that
        are smaller than currEle? 
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example demonstrates the usage of erase-remove_if. `limit` is captured by reference and can thus be modified outside the lambda:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int size = vec.size();
    for (int limit = 0; limit <= size; limit++)
    {
        vec.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [&limit](int i) {
            return i < limit;
        }), std::end(vec));
        for (auto& v : vec)
            std::cout << v;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
0123456789
123456789
23456789
3456789
456789
56789
6789
789
89
9
```

Comment: Great that you provided an answer. If you can give some simple explanatory text, that can be even more helpful to people trying to solve problems, not only the original questioner but also others coming to this page in future.